# Change a value in a csv file with c#

Tags: c#, csv

I've made a simple application that lets you login and you can click forget password (The forget password is the main part of this application)

The csv File is structured like: Username, Password, Role, IDnumber

I can read these values from my CSV File well and it all works perfectly but what im trying to do is allow a user to change the password if they type the correct username and id number.

My code for reading CSV File

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\hughesa3\\Desktop\\test environment\\users.csv", encoding);

        foreach (var line in csvLines)
        {
            var values = line.Split(',');
            if (values[0].Contains(textBox1.Text) && textBox2.Text == values[3]) // Textbox 1 = Username & Values[3] Is there ID Number
            {
                Form3 form = new Form3();
                form.Show(); // This loads the new form with the fields new password and confirm password.
            }
        }
    }
```

So the value I would need to change is Value[1]
I can do the checks to see if both passwords match but when I'm unsure how to overwrite just values[1]. I've tried googling about and seen some stuff with StreamWriter and StreamReader but when i tried to implement it I just get numerous errors. Is anybody able to advise or possibly hint at another way of doing this?

If anymore info is needed please say. Thanks.

Comment: How many users accessing your application simultaneously?

Comment: @Chris Its just an exercise I'm doing for apprenticeship coursework so there's only 5 or so users in the csv file. And it will only be 1 user at a time. Thanks

Comment: If the user(s) can access your application one at a time, you can store the retrieved data into a list of object and from there your can use LINQ to modify the data, once modified you can overwrite the existing csv file. That is only my suggestion or comment.

Comment: You can try using File.WriteAllLines. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can user libraries like [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) and [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) to read and write CSV files.

As it is only coursework application you may overwrite entire file on changing a data for a user.

Your algorithm can be:

1. Read the CSV file into the array.
2. Find a user record
3. Update the record
4. Store the array into the CSV file.

You can do it with or without libraries I mentioned before.